# From a song: "Tu coules, tu vises ----" I don't know what the ---- should be

Tags: paroles-de-chanson

I am having a hard time understanding this part in this music video:

> Tu coules, tu vises ----

It sounds like "blimmy dall" *(pronouncing with English pronunciation)*.

Can someone have a listen? I linked the video at the necessary timestamp: https://youtu.be/7Hj86jsDOcU?t=25

Comment: I'm 99% sure that's English, 'let me die' or 'let me dive'. Lots of other lines in the song have English lyrics too (e.g., 'my lover', 'insane')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm certain I'm hearing something close to a word ending in *-tard*. Before this there's a short sound ending with a high "ee". I've played that back at 0.25x and I don't really get it and I'm a native speaker. I speculate that's "mi-", so "[mitard](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mitard)", some slang word for solitary confinement. This video is based on a cover of *Blank Space* by Taylor Swift and by reading the lyrics I can extrapolate as to what this is referring to, for instance "I can make the bad guys good for a weekend" and "'Cause you know I love the players/And you love the game". So I understand your sentence as someone "aiming" (*viser*) for (destined to, setting themselves up for/to?) jail, a bad boy; or is this someone *going for it* (sex). Then follows "Non, non, non, je ne veux pas de ça", ie. "I don't want any of that", not for more than a weekend I guess... By the way, what you're listining to is not an accurate translation of Swift's lyrics, not by a long shot.

---

*Sources*

From the subs and what I hear from your link:

> Nuit, monnaie, se saouler tard
>  C'est pas en feuilletant que ton
> magazine (sic)
>  Tu coules, tu vises le ----- [mitard]
>  Nan, nan,
> nan j'veux pas de ça
>  Désolée de devenir dingue
>  Te fais[faire]
> passer après ----- [tes friends]
>  Prends mon style[stylo] comme
> ----- [un flingue] (sic)
>  Si je te tue c'est que j'ai raison donc crève ce week-end
>  Quand je te vois, je fais un voeu
>  Mon étoile
> filante c'est toi je l'sais
>  Dis-moi, dis-moi ce que tu veux
>  Je
> ne voudrais pas t'embêter [we hear "n'arrêterais"]
>  Reviens,
> reviens my lover
>  Appelle-moi "I'm insane" [we hear something else
> than "I'm insane", "par l'essai" or what not]
>  Ou sinon je rappuie
> sur player
>  Écoute --- [jip] jippick
>  Tout ce qui aime que tu
> regresses (nonsensical)
>  Sont tout autour de toi
>  Et aimeraient
> que tu délaisses, ta femme, ta foi, ton toit
>  Désolée j'ai des
> larmes dans la voix
>  C'est mon espoir qui saigne
>  Regardes la
> place baby
>  C'est maintenant ou jamais
>  Quand tu me fuis, quand
> je doute de ce que je suis
>  Tu touches de suite à mon égo
> (nonsensical)
>  Alors je prie quand je sais que ta beauté peut
> attirer un tas de *gow* [possibly [slang](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/gow) for gf] 
>  Ce que tu dégages c'est c'qui me
> laisse (nonsensical)
>  Ce côté sauvage quand tu me délaisses [ambiguous]
>  Je
> veux tourner la page dans le sens inverse [non idiomatic]
>  Enfin
> tout recommencer
>  J'suis dans un parc, baskets aux pieds
>  J'fais
> mon sport et là
>  J'suis au départ, t'es arrivé [we
> hear "l'arrivée", which would be better]
>  Arrivé de nulle part et chaviré [Î hear
> "déchaviré" (sic)]
> ---- [Je t'ai fait gaillard] un bon moment
>  Puis je dis "Stop" c'est le moment
>  On s'est pris la main par le destin [I hear "du"
> instead of "le", nonsensical either way]
>  C'est là où tout a
> commencé
>  Quand je te vois je fais un voeu
>  Mon étoile filante
> c'est toi je l'sais
>  Dis-moi, dis-moi ce que tu veux
>  Je ne
> voudrais pas t'embêter [we hear "n'arrêterais"]
>  Reviens, reviens
> my lover
>  Appelle-moi "I'm insane" [we hear something else than
> "I'm insane", "par l'essai" or what not]
>  Ou sinon rappuie sur
> player
>  Écoute --- [jip] jippick
>  Tout ce qui aime que tu
> regresses (nonsensical)
>  Sont tout autour de toi
>  Et aimeraient
> que tu délaisses, ta femme, ta foi, ton toit
>  Désolée j'ai des
> larmes dans la voix
>  C'est mon espoir qui saigne
>  Regardes la
> place baby
>  C'est maintenant ou jamais

I fed that to *DeepL* just for fun:

> Night, money, getting drunk late
>  It's not by leafing through your
> magazine
>  You're going down, you're going to jail
>  No, no, no I
> don't want that
>  I'm sorry I'm going crazy
>  Make you take second
> place to your friends
>  Take my pen like a gun
>  If I kill you I'm
> right so die this weekend
>  When I see you I make a wish
>  My
> shooting star is you I know
>  Tell me, tell me what you want
>  I
> don't want to bother you
>  Come back, come back my lover
>  Call me
> "I'm insane
>  Or else I'll hit the player
>  Listen to jip
> jippick
>  Everything that likes you to regress
>  Are all around
> you
>  And would like you to leave, your wife, your faith, your
> roof
>  Sorry I've got tears in my voice
>  It's my hope that
> bleeds
>  Look at the square baby
>  It's now or never
>  When you
> run away from me, when I doubt what I am
>  You touch my ego right
> away
>  So I pray when I know your beauty can attract a lot of
> gow
>  What you give off is what leaves me
>  That wild side when
> you leave me
>  I want to turn the page in the opposite direction
> I want to start all over again
>  I'm in a park, sneakers on my
> feet
>  I'm doing my sport and there
>  I'm at the start, you've
> arrived
>  I've got to get out of here, I've got to get out of
> here
>  I've been doing you a solid for a while
>  Then I say "Stop"
> it's time
>  We've taken each other's hands by fate
>  That's where
> it all began
>  When I see you I make a wish
>  My shooting star is
> you I know
>  Tell me, tell me what you wish
>  I don't want to
> bother you
>  Come back, come back my lover
>  Call me "I'm
> insane
>  Or else hit the player
>  Listen to jip jippick
> Everything that likes you to regress
>  Are all around you
>  And
> would like you to leave, your wife, your faith, your roof
>  Sorry
> I've got tears in my voice
>  It's my hope that bleeds
>  Look at
> the square baby
>  It's now or never

---

Now let's take a look at the original *Blank Space* lyrics from Taylor Swift:

> Nice to meet you, where you been?
>  I could show you incredible
> things
>  Magic, madness, heaven, sin
>  Saw you there and I
> thought
>  "Oh, my God, look at that face
>  You look like my next
> mistake
>  Love's a game, wanna play?" Ay
>  New money, suit and
> tie
>  I can read you like a magazine
>  Ain't it funny? Rumors
> fly
>  And I know you heard about me
>  So hey, let's be friends
> I'm dying to see how this one ends
>  Grab your passport and my
> hand
>  I can make the bad guys good for a weekend
>  So it's gonna
> be forever
>  Or it's gonna go down in flames
>  You can tell me
> when it's over, hmm
>  If the high was worth the pain
>  Got a long
> list of ex-lovers
>  They'll tell you I'm insane
>  'Cause you know
> I love the players
>  And you love the game
>  'Cause we're young,
> and we're reckless
>  We'll take this way too far
>  It'll leave you
> breathless, hmm
>  Or with a nasty scar
>  Got a long list of
> ex-lovers
>  They'll tell you I'm insane
>  But I've got a blank
> space, baby
>  And I'll write your name
>  Cherry lips, crystal
> skies
>  I could show you incredible things
>  Stolen kisses, pretty
> lies
>  You're the King, baby, I'm your Queen
>  Find out what you
> want
>  Be that girl for a month
>  Wait, the worst is yet to come,
> oh, no
>  Screaming, crying, perfect storms
>  I can make all the
> tables turn
>  Rose garden filled with thorns
>  Keep you second
> guessing like
>  "Oh, my God, who is she?"
>  I get drunk on
> jealousy
>  But you'll come back each time you leave
>  'Cause,
> darling, I'm a nightmare dressed like a daydream
>  So it's gonna be
> forever
>  Or it's gonna go down in flames
>  You can tell me when
> it's over, hmm
>  If the high was worth the pain
>  Got a long list
> of ex-lovers
>  They'll tell you I'm insane
>  'Cause you know I
> love the players
>  And you love the game
>  'Cause we're young, and
> we're reckless (oh)
>  We'll take this way too far
>  It'll leave
> you breathless, hmm (oh)
>  Or with a nasty scar
>  Got a long list
> of ex-lovers
>  They'll tell you I'm insane (insane)
>  But I've got
> a blank space, baby
>  And I'll write your name
>  Boys only want
> love if it's torture
>  Don't say I didn't, say I didn't warn ya
> Boys only want love if it's torture
>  Don't say I didn't, say I
> didn't warn ya
>  So it's gonna be forever
>  Or it's gonna go down
> in flames
>  You can tell me when it's over (over)
>  If the high
> was worth the pain
>  Got a long list of ex-lovers
>  They'll tell
> you I'm insane (I'm insane)
>  'Cause you know I love the players
> And you love the game
>  'Cause we're young, and we're reckless
> We'll take this way too far (ooh)
>  It'll leave you breathless,
> hmm
>  Or with a nasty scar (leave a nasty scar)
>  Got a long list
> of ex-lovers
>  They'll tell you I'm insane
>  But I've got a blank
> space, baby
>  And I'll write your name

---

Finally let's feed these original lyrics to DeepL:

> Enchanté de vous rencontrer, où étiez-vous ?
>  Je pourrais vous
> montrer des choses incroyables
>  Magie, folie, paradis, péché
>  Je
> t'ai vu là et j'ai pensé
>  "Oh, mon Dieu, regarde ce visage
>  Tu
> ressembles à ma prochaine erreur
>  L'amour est un jeu, tu veux jouer
> ?" Ay
>  Nouvel argent, costume et cravate
>  Je peux te lire comme
> un magazine
>  C'est drôle, non ? Les rumeurs vont bon train
>  Et
> je sais que tu as entendu parler de moi
>  Alors hey, soyons amis
> Je meurs d'envie de voir comment ça se termine.
>  Prends ton
> passeport et ma main
>  Je peux rendre les méchants gentils pour un
> week-end.
>  Alors ce sera pour toujours
>  Ou ça va partir en
> fumée.
>  Tu peux me dire quand c'est fini, hmm...
>  Si l'euphorie
> valait la douleur
>  J'ai une longue liste d'ex-amants
>  Ils te
> diront que je suis fou.
>  Parce que tu sais que j'aime les
> joueurs
>  Et tu aimes le jeu
>  Parce qu'on est jeunes et
> imprudents
>  On va aller trop loin
>  Vous aurez le souffle coupé,
> hmm.
>  Ou avec une vilaine cicatrice
>  J'ai une longue liste
> d'ex-amants
>  Ils vous diront que je suis fou.
>  Mais j'ai un
> espace vierge, bébé
>  Et j'écrirai ton nom
>  Lèvres de cerise,
> cieux de cristal
>  Je pourrais te montrer des choses incroyables
> Baisers volés, jolis mensonges
>  Tu es le roi, bébé, je suis ta
> reine.
>  Découvre ce que tu veux
>  Sois cette fille pendant un
> mois
>  Attends, le pire est encore à venir, oh, non.
>  Des cris,
> des pleurs, des tempêtes parfaites
>  Je peux faire tourner toutes
> les tables
>  Un jardin de roses rempli d'épines
>  Vous laissant
> dans l'expectative comme
>  "Oh, mon Dieu, qui est-elle ?"
>  Je me
> saoule de jalousie
>  Mais tu reviendras à chaque fois que tu
> partiras
>  Car, chéri, je suis un cauchemar déguisé en rêve
> éveillé.
>  So it's gonna be forever
>  Ou ça va s'envoler en
> fumée.
>  Tu peux me dire quand c'est fini, hmm.
>  If the high was
> worth the pain
>  J'ai une longue liste d'ex-amants
>  Ils te diront
> que je suis fou.
>  Parce que tu sais que j'aime les joueurs
>  Et
> tu aimes le jeu
>  Parce qu'on est jeunes et qu'on est insouciants
> (oh)
>  On va aller trop loin
>  Ça te laissera sans souffle, hmm
> (oh)
>  Ou avec une vilaine cicatrice
>  J'ai une longue liste
> d'ex-amants
>  Ils vous diront que je suis fou (fou)
>  Mais j'ai un
> espace vide, bébé
>  Et je vais écrire ton nom
>  Les garçons ne
> veulent de l'amour que si c'est une torture
>  Ne dis pas que je ne
> l'ai pas fait, que je ne t'ai pas prévenue.
>  Les garçons ne veulent
> de l'amour que si c'est une torture
>  Ne dis pas que je ne l'ai pas
> fait, que je ne t'ai pas prévenu
>  So it's gonna be forever
>  Or
> it's gonna go down in flames
>  Tu peux me dire quand c'est fini
> (fini)
>  Si l'euphorie valait la douleur
>  J'ai une longue liste
> d'ex-amants
>  Ils te diront que je suis fou (je suis fou)
>  Parce
> que tu sais que j'aime les joueurs
>  Et tu aimes le jeu
>  Parce
> qu'on est jeunes et imprudents
>  On va aller trop loin (ooh)
>  Ça
> te laissera sans souffle, hmm.
>  Ou avec une vilaine cicatrice
> (laisse une vilaine cicatrice)
>  J'ai une longue liste
> d'ex-amants
>  Ils te diront que je suis fou.
>  Mais j'ai un espace
> vide, bébé
>  Et je vais écrire ton nom

Naturally this looks nothing like what we began with but you can compare the lyrics and that might prove insightful. I've done my part.

Comment: I've listened a dozen times at various speeds, it definitely sounds like _le mi tar_ so I think "le mitard" is correct.

Comment: Thanks. If no later answers come within 7 days, this bounty goes to you :)

Comment: I think that the *"gow"* that they are referring to the the English word meaning "girl" or "chick". https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gow

Comment: Thank you for the reward! If you have similar questions in the future, don't hesitate to ask.